# How do you test for a routing error in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing

After searching, can't find the answer to this simple question. Yes, I read the Guides many times.

Here's what I got so far.

```
test "there is no route for this request" do
  assert_raise(Exception) {
    post :the_route
  }
end
```

The browser shows

Are there any resources that explain the basics of testing (besides the Guides)?

Thanks.

Comment: OK, I found the answer: `assert_raise(ActionController::RoutingError) {`. You have to look at the server output to find the exact error. Don't search in the API docs. You won't find "routingerror".

Comment: @B Seven: Where in the documentation would you expect to see this? You do know Rails is open source, right? And that documentation patches are more than welcome?

Comment: @Ryan: That's a good point. I can improve them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked into the routing assertions at all? They could be what you're looking for. Most app's I've worked on have at least one "routes_test". check them out here:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Assertions/RoutingAssertions.html